# Accept Certificate (.p12) in C# selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, certificate, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to find a way how to accept a certificate popup window in C# selenium.

I tried several ways.. nothing helped.

```
new Thread(() =>
{
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
}).Start();
driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept(); // here I tried many type of ways to accept the popup, also key:enter ...
```

also I tried some ignore stuff to add in 
`chromeOptions.AddArguments();` but it didn't help neither.

several ideas are not actual - for example `DesiredCapabilities` is not available anymore.

didn't help:

```
options.AddArgument("ignore-certificate-errors");
chromeOptions.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.AcceptSslCertificates, true);
```

[image]

thank you for any idea or support

Answer (score 0):

The following code works (with "--" at the beginning of the option name):

```cs
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--ignore-certificate-errors");

var chromeDriverLocation = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ChromeWebDriver");
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(chromeDriverLocation))
{
    chromeDriverLocation = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
}
WebDriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverLocation, chromeOptions);
```

(Full code is [here](https://github.com/devpro/withywoods/blob/master/src/Selenium/SeleniumTestBase.cs))

Comment: It's not answering the question, the OP asking for the accept .p12 certificate not to ignore.